# Images associated with records do not return in the Laravel view

Tags: php, laravel

I am unable to display the images associated with the character in the view,I already used `php artisan storage:link`, the path of my images are `storage/app/avatars/{id}/image.png`

- `CharacterModel.php`

```
class CharacterModel extends Model
{

    public function avatarCharacter()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AvatarCharacterModel::class, 'character_id');
    }

}
```

- `index.php`

```
<td>
     @foreach ($hxh->avatarCharacter as $avatar)
        <img src="{{ asset($avatar->image) }}" height="100" width="100" style="margin: 5px">
     @endforeach
</td>
```

Comment: your image.png is not public on the path you have provided, storage:link links the public folder, not avatars

Comment: I tried ```asset("storage/{$avatar->image}")```, did not work.

Comment: The address of image to example is ```"file:///home/bebop/Laravel/test-laravel/storage/app/avatars/1/Screenshot%20from%202023-11-10%2012-45-44.png"```.

Comment: the path `storage/app/avatars` is not a public path for your web server, `storage/app/public` on the other hand is public. Either store your avatars on the public disk or make a controller that can serve files on the avatars directory.

Comment: I doesn't still pass the right way to show the images in code.